# What is the best way to store MySQL database for Android apps

Tags: android, mysql, database

I know this is not a type of question that should be asked on this platform,  but I really need an good insight from the people who have worked in this field. I want to set up a database for my Android app. My app has no Image or Media data, it's all text for now, like user posts, likes and dislikes. I am thinking of storing all this in SQL tables. I want to perform tasks like auto deletion of entries after a certain time they have been entered. Store likes and dislikes, deletion of posts based on their dislikes, (if dislikes cross certain threshold, I want the post to be deleted.) I was thinking of using PHP and use hosting from a basic hosting provider like, hostgator or something like that. Though I am worried about the performance. For now I don't expect large no of users, only few hundred a day. But they will be interacting with the database all the time for eg, liking a post, disliking a post etc. It would be really nice if someone could guide me into right path. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to develop web services for doing that.According to me rest api is best for the task you wanna do.
check the link for demo.
http://www.androidhive.info/2014/01/how-to-create-rest-api-for-android-app-using-php-slim-and-mysql-day-12-2/

Answer (score 0):

You could use the inbuilt SQLite database which is standard in android development or you store them in a backend on your server on a MySQL instance and the app can access your data over a restful webservice.